# phonegap android cannot read image file

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am developing hybrid using phonegap 3.3. I am using camera plugin to capture image and store into photo album which working fine. Later, I have to read image file from the device storage.

I am using the following code.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, failFS);
function gotFS(fileSystem){
    fileSystem.root.getFile(imageData, {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
function gotFileEntry(){
    fileEntry.file(gotFile,fail);
}
function gotFile(file){
    alert(file.getParent().fullPath);
}
```

I am getting error in the first line. It is giving

> FileError.ENCODING_ERR

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. After, I have to move to another directory with new name. Could anyone help me to fix.

I am using camera plugin for capture images and file plugin to read files and directory.

--Sridhar

Comment: can u tell me what is the data in "imageData" field?

Comment: @BhaveshParekh imageData is the full path of the image file

Comment: Have you check my answer below. in that i have used window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI instead of window.requestFileSystem

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code to capture and copy image

```
var pictureSource;
var destinationType;

var FileFolder = "";
var FileName = "";

var obj_imageCapture = {
    capturePicture:function(imgFolder,imgName)
    {

        var image = imgFolder + imgName;

        FileFolder = imgFolder;
        FileName = imgName;

        pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;

        navigator.camera.getPicture(obj_imageCapture.onPhotoDataSuccess1, obj_imageCapture.onFail, {quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI , saveToPhotoAlbum: true });

     },
     onPhotoDataSuccess1:function(imageData){

     obj_imageCapture.createFileEntry(imageData);


   },
   createFileEntry:function(imageURI) {
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, obj_imageCapture.copyPhoto, obj_imageCapture.onFFail);
   },
   copyPhoto:function(fileEntry) {
   try
   {


        var ext = fileEntry.fullPath.substr(fileEntry.fullPath.lastIndexOf('.'));



        var imageN = "";

        if(FileName.indexOf('.') > 0)
        {
            imageN = FileName.substr(0,FileName.lastIndexOf('.')) + ext;
        }
        else
        {
            imageN = FileName + ext;
        }




        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {
                                 fileSys.root.getDirectory(FileFolder, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dir) {
                                                           fileEntry.copyTo(dir, imageN, obj_imageCapture.onCopySuccess, obj_imageCapture.onFFail);
                                                           }, obj_imageCapture.onFFail);
                                 }, obj_imageCapture.onFFail);
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        alert(ex.message);
    }

    },
    onCopySuccess:function(entry) {


        var smallimage = document.getElementById("myimage");
        smallimage.style.display = "block";
        smallimage.src = entry.fullPath + "?rand=" + Math.random();



    },
    onFFail:function(message)
    {
        alert("Error in photo : " + message.message);
    }
};
```

Above code might helpful to you